# Turn on bluetooth when USB is connected?

Tags: bluetooth, usb

Is there any app, or other method, that lets me automatically turn on Bluetooth if USB is also connected, and turn it off when USB is disconnected?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure because I've never used the app myself, but knowing that it has a million features I'm sure Tasker could handle this.

[Tasker](http://market.android.com/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm)

[image: Tasker QR Code]

Comment: I'm sure it could do it, +1.

Comment: Great find! It has turned out to be useful for more than just this situation.

Answer (score 1):

The Locale app might also be able to do this.